# Processing policy of Websockets using DataPower

Tags: websocket, ibm-datapower

if someone is using IBM-Datapower as the organization firewall and the go-to tool for policy processing (like look into the traffic, schema checking and some other over the line processing). How this is possible to do it, if the protocol of transportation is WebSockets (DP version is 7.6)? 
if it is not possible, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Once it is elevated to WebSocket you can process any data in a DataPower Processing Policy.
You should set the Rule to be both directions and a match rule of "match-all" (URL=*).

You might also need "Process Backend Errors"  and "Proxy HTTP Response" set in the Advanced settings of the MPGW...

Depending on your needs it might be better to build separate rules and call them through "call processing rule", bulid a "GatewayScript router" which can call or load GWS modules/Script or add an XMLFW as a "micro-service" gateway.

Comment: for what version of DP are you referring to? I just checked and there is no way visible to change the processing policy after the upgrade to websockets. 
can you elaborate please?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "change the processing policy after the upgrade to websockets"... You need to build the Processing Policy prior to running the connection and save it into the configuration run-time. When you are running DataPower and have active connections you can't change them. If you make changes and hit "Apply" in DataPower it will only use those new changes for new connections, not already established ones.